# How to draw an image to four points in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame

So, is it *possible* to draw an image to four points in pygame?
Like this:
[(Image demonstration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClMbR.png)

Comment: You don't. Not with Pygame unless you use PyOpengl

Answer (score 0):

From the [pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)

```
# Importing the library
import pygame

# Initializing Pygame
pygame.init()

# Initializing surface
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))

# Initialing Color
color = (255,0,0)

# Drawing Rectangle
pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You completely misunderstood the question. The task is to fill a 4-point polygon with an image. This just draws a rectangle